# How can I change the text on a property sheet APPLY button

Tags: winapi, propertysheet

I'd like to change the text on a property sheet APPLY button but I don't know the control's ID or HWND.  I do have the property sheet's HWND.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of instances where folks included the following defines...

```
#define IDD_APPLYNOW 0x3021
#define IDD_DLGFRAME 0x3022
#define IDD_BACK 0x3023
#define IDD_NEXT 0x3024
#define IDD_FINISH 0x3025
#define IDD_DIVIDER 0x3026
#define IDD_TOPDIVIDER 0x3027
```

Using IDD_APPLYNOW per above I was able to change the text on the button,

```
SetDlgItemText (hwndPS,0x3021,"Validate");
```

Don't have much of an idea what the other symbols might be; look like some are for wizard property sheets.